# Serialization of generic collections in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, generics, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize a Dictionary with protobuf-net but still getting "Unexpected sub-type: " exception with generic lists.

This is how I construct the dictionary:

```
        var list = new List<DummyObject1>();
        list.Add(new DummyObject1());

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict["0"] = new DummyObject1();
        dict["1"] = new DummyObject1();
        dict["2"] = list;
```

I added the types to the default model with

```
        model.Add(typeof(object), true);
        model.Add(typeof (DummyObject1), true);
```

Is there any solution or workaround for this situation?

Edit: I made it work with a workaround like this;

First I wrote a wrapper class for List

```
        public class ListWrapper
        {
            public List<object> Items { get; set; }
        }
```

and I registered the type and Items field

```
        ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ListWrapper));
        ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(ListWrapper)].AddField(1, "Items");
```

Now I can serialize and deserialize a dictionary

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict["0"] = new DummyObject1();
        var lw = new ListWrapper { Items = new List<object> { new DummyObject1() } };
        dict["2"] = lw;


        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, dict);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var req = Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(stream);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, protobuf-net does not play nicely with `object`, and will always struggle with (for example) a `Dictionary<string,object>`. That isn't a supported use case, as the google protobuf specification expects data to follow a single contract end-to-end. I can spoof around that for *some* inheritance scenarios, but `object` is *just too vague*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used a wrapper class ListWrapper<T> instead of List<T> and I got rid of the exception but now I can't deserialize the list which is wrapped by ListWrapper<T> class. Can I fix this?

Comment: @ocozalp hard to comment without seeing `ListWrapper<T>` ;p

Comment: public class ListWrapper {public List<object> Items { get; set; }} :))

Comment: @ocozalp well, that is still using `object`, so it still isn't going to work - plus, unless you add some field-markers (or configure it in code), there is *nothing to serialize there* - needs some `[ProtoMember(1)]` or similar

Comment: This makes me sad. :( I'm using a port of apache openNLP. I started out using IKVM but the model loading time is horrible, it's no better somehow even in a direct C# port. Guess it's just the way the library was built. Anyway I started plugging in protobuf-net to solve this problem, but I'm getting incomplete output from the serializer. After reading this, I'm now concluding that it's the <string,object> dicts used in the code to work around the gross java pseudo-generics inherited from the original library.